# Why does the jQuery change event fire repeatedly for an ASP.NET Listbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following code in my ASP.NET web form page:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

     myListBox_OnChangeHandler();

  });

  function myListBox_OnChangeHandler() {
     $('#<%= myListBox.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        alert('Worked');
     });
  }
```

Here is my ListBox:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

The `jQuery` to wire up the handler to the `change` event of the ListBox actually works, but a little to well. The method is called a compounded number of times every time a new selection is made. For example, click 1, no alert, click 2, 2 alerts, click 3, 4 alerts, etc.. Not that there will be an `alert` there in this method for real (I also tried just declaring a variable and placing a breakpoint and removed the `alert` and it still behaved the same), but I wanted to make sure it worked.

However if I change my `ListBox` and define its `onchange` client side event and point it to the method like below it works:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ui_lbxAdUsers" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="myListBox_OnChangeHandler();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

...and change the `JS` to this:

```
  function myListBox_OnChangeHandler() {
     alert('Worked');
  }
```

...everything works perfectly. I prefer to wire up my handlers in an organized manner via the `$(document).ready` function and using `jQuery` but the repeated calls are a showstopper for that method.

Why does using the 1st Method result in the method getting called a compounded number of times for each click change in the `ListBox`, but not happening in the 2nd method where I declare the `onchange` event on the control?

Comment: If the alert multiplies every time the change event is fired, you're probably attaching an event handler inside an event handler, binding the same event multiple times.

Comment: Why does it then work if I use the identical code but just declare the `onchange` event on the control instead?

Comment: Because then the event handler is only added once.

Comment: You haven't mentioned why there is an `AutoPostBack="true"`.  I'm willing to bet you have in your code base some "fix" for ajax loaded controls that automatically binds the `change` event handler for every successful ajax post, whether or not the `select` was reloaded into the DOM.  This would be in error if the `select` was not reloaded as then it would accumulate event handlers. Of course this is pure speculation—which is why I posted a comment instead of answering.